# How to get these values with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this html table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="datax">a</td>
        <td class="datax">b</td>
        <td class="datax">c</td>
        <td class="datax">d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="datax">e</td>
        <td class="datax">f</td>
        <td class="datax">g</td>
        <td class="datax">h</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to get the second and the fourth value of each `<tr>` ?
If i do:

```
bs.findAll('td', {'class':'datax'})
```

I get:

```
        <td class="datax">a</td>
        <td class="datax">b</td>
        <td class="datax">c</td>
        <td class="datax">d</td>

        <td class="datax">e</td>
        <td class="datax">f</td>
        <td class="datax">g</td>
        <td class="datax">h</td>
```

it's correct! but I would like to have this result:

```
        <td class="datax">b</td>
        <td class="datax">d</td>

        <td class="datax">f</td>
        <td class="datax">h</td>
```

so, the values I want are -> **b - d - f - h**

(the second and the forth `<td>` of each `<tr>`)

Is it possible with BeautifulSoup module?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

This should do it~

```
final_values=[td.string for td in bs.findAll('td', {'class':'datax'})[1::2]]
```

(after comment clarification) for your specific case it would be:

```
final_values=[td.b.a.string for td in bs.findAll('td', {'class':'datax'})[1::2]]
```

Comment: >>> [td.string for td in soup.findAll('td', {'class':'datax'})[1::2]]
[u'b', u'd', u'f', u'h']

unless bs isn't BeautifulSoup(source) this should work fine

Comment: hmmm i checked... td.string is None beacuse the value of td is -> <td class="datax"><b><a href="/q?s=AAU">AAU</a></b></td>  (i have to get AAU)

Comment: [td.b.a.string for td in bs.findAll('td', {'class':'datax'})[1::2]]

Comment: ok, works! but the first has an <a href> the second no. So td.b.a.contents is wrong (works for the first but not for the second) how to do? thank you really much!

Comment: hmm I tried...but 1::2 doesn't works! i also get others colums values

Comment: @Damiano, you need to understand what 1::2 (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange) means and look into the BeautifulSoup doc. After that, you can adapt the code whatever the way you like.

Answer (score -2):

I know using HTQL, it is simple:

<tr>.<td>2,4

--

HTQL only has COM support thought.  Here is a complete example in javascript:

<html> 
<body> 
<script language=JavaScript> 
        var a= new ActiveXObject("HtqlCom.HtqlControl"); 
        a.setUrl("C:\\test_table.html"); 
        a.setQuery("<tr>.<td>2,4"); 
        for (a.moveFirst(); !a.isEOF(); a.moveNext()){ 
                document.write(a.getValueByIndex(1)); 
        } 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>

Comment: what? Could you give me a complete example?

thank you very much!